# What is the recommended method for blanking inputs in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a small subset of fields that need blanked on a page (so I can't just run something using :input).

At the moment the code is something like this..

```
$('#txt1').val('');
$('#txt2').val('');
$('#txt3').val('');
```

Is it more efficient to chain them or is there some other method entirely I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#txt1, #txt2, #txt3').val('');
```

Or:

```
$('#txt1, #txt2, #txt3').empty();
```

As can be seen, you can combine multiple selectors by separating them with a comma.

---

Alternatively you can apply a class to fields you want to clear the text of and use the class in the selector like this:

```
$('.empty').empty();
```

where your fiels should look like:

```
<input class='empty' name="name1" />
<input class='empty' name="name2" />
<input class='empty' name="name3" />
```

Comment: Comma separated selectors are very slow though.

Comment: @Toby: That's why i have suggested class-based approach if you can see :)

Comment: I did see that cheers and I think that is the way forward, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can select them all at once:

```
$('#txt1, #txt2, #txt3').val('');
```

<s>This won't make a significant difference, but probably will make a small improvement.</s>  The biggest improvement is in making your code less repetitive and therefore easier to follow.

Edit: [In fact, this makes the selection significantly slower.](http://jsperf.com/multiple-selections-vs-multiple-selection) This is because selections by a single ID are *very* fast. `document.getElementById` is quicker than `document.querySelectorAll`.  Stick with what you have.

Comment: You could make it *slightly* better using `$('#txt1').add('#txt2').add('#txt3#').val('');`, but the class approach is a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a class to each...

**HTML**

```
<input class='blankable' type=... />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.blankable').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i would do it with one line and null, but i guess its however you prefer it:

```
<input value="foo" id="txt1" />
<input value="foo" id="txt2" />
<input value="foo" id="txt3" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt1, #txt2, #txt3').val(null);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that setting `.val('')` will not work for all types of `:input` elements.

I use the following function which may not be complete but covers all the scenarios my application currently encounters.

```
function clearForm($container) {
    $(':input', $container).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
        if (!$(this).attr('readonly')) {
            var type = this.type;
            if (type == 'text' || type == 'file')
                this.value = "";
            else if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select')
                this.selectedIndex = 0;
            // checkboxes need to have their checked state cleared
            // but should *not* have their 'value' changed
            else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
                this.checked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(':input').val('');` should select all your inputs and clear the value. I do not know however if `<select>` and `<textarea>` need special attention. Also, you might need to exclude invisible inputs if you have `<input type="hidden">`. In that case, consider:

```
jQuery('[type!="hidden"]:input').val('');
```

#### EDIT

Just read that I missed something. If you are selecting from a subset, select the subset first.

```
jQuery('#subset :input').val('');
```